# How do I inherit abstract unit tests in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, inheritance, testunit

I have two unit tests that should share a lot of common tests with slightly different setup methods.  If I write something like

```
class Abstract < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @field = create
  end

  def test_1
    ...
  end
end

class Concrete1 < Abstract
  def create
    SomeClass1.new
  end
end

class Concrete2 < Abstract
  def create
    SomeClass2.new
  end
end
```

then Concrete1 does not seem to inherit the tests from Abstract.  Or at least I cannot get them to run in eclipse.  If I choose "Run all TestCases" for the file that contains Concrete1 then Abstract is run even though I do not want it to be.  If I specify Concrete1 then it does not run any tests at all!  If I specify test_1 in Concrete1 then it complains it cannot find it ("uncaught throw :invalid_test (ArgumentError)").

I'm new to Ruby.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that, as far as I can tell, `Test::Unit` keeps track of which classes inherit from `Test::Unit::TestCase`, and as a result, will *only* run tests from classes that *directly* inherit from it.

The way to work around this is to create a module with the tests you want, and then *include* that module in the classes that derive from `Test::Unit::TestCase`.

```
require 'test/unit'

module TestsToInclude
  def test_name
    assert(self.class.name.start_with?("Concrete"))
  end
end

class Concrete1 < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include TestsToInclude

  def test_something_bad
    assert(false)
  end
end

class Concrete2 < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include TestsToInclude

  def test_something_good
    assert(true)
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Loaded suite a
Started
.F..
Finished in 0.027873 seconds.

  1) Failure:
test_something_bad(Concrete1) [a.rb:13]:
<false> is not true.

4 tests, 4 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors

shell returned 1
```

Comment: Thanks - this is great!  It helped me finally solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888614/how-to-write-and-inherit-from-an-abstract-subclass-of-actioncontrollertestcase which is set in the context of Rails functional (controller) tests, and as such has a little extra challenge.

Comment: One other observation: unfortunately it seems that this approach does not allow overriding of the included tests.  I guess another hack will be needed to work around that :-(

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. If test classes must directly inherit from Test::Unit::TestCase, how do ActiveSupport::TestCase and ActionController::TestCase not cause the problem described in this question?  Aren't they both just additional levels of inheritance between Test::Unit::TestCase and the concrete classes?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Test::Unit::TestCase` explicitly doesn't run tests defined in superclasses by default. In particular, note that `TestSuiteCreator` does not run tests unless `Test::Unit::TestCase#valid?` returns true (https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/blob/2.5.5/lib/test/unit/testsuitecreator.rb#L40):

```
def append_test(suite, test_name)
  test = @test_case.new(test_name)
  yield(test) if block_given?
  suite << test if test.valid?
end
```

And what determines if a test case is valid? A test case is valid by default if the this class explicitly defined that method, or if the method was defined in a `Module` (https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/blob/2.5.5/lib/test/unit/testcase.rb#L405-L418):

```
def valid? # :nodoc:
  return false unless respond_to?(@method_name)
  test_method = method(@method_name)
  if @internal_data.have_test_data?
    return false unless test_method.arity == 1
  else
    return false unless test_method.arity <= 0
  end
  owner = Util::MethodOwnerFinder.find(self, @method_name)
  if owner.class != Module and self.class != owner
    return false
  end
  true
end
```

So basically, if you subclass another unit test class, and you want to run the superclass's unit tests, you can either:

- Redefine those test methods in your subclass and have them call your superclass's test method
- Move all your methods to a module (as explained in the other answer in this thread)
- Redefine the `valid?` method in your subclass to return true:

`def valid?
  return true
end`